# comments meta box not showing in my plugin post type

Tags: plugins, php, comments-template

I´m still pretty new to coding, I might not understand lingo very well, but let me explain the best I can.

here is an image of what I want. this is the comic easel plugin. I have comments checked in the screen options, and it shows in the editor.

[image: screen options in comic easel]
comments meta box showing
[image: comments showing]

you can see the comments with a add comment button.

now in the plugin that I am having trouble with is Chapters_for_authors.
in the supports => array() I added 'comments' and the discussion box appeared, and
I have Discussion checked

[image]

I have been able to make comments on my web post. and i can find the comments in the comments section of dashboard.

but in the chapters post editor screen options comments are not available.

[image: chapters screen options]

I can only find questions that say check screen options, or edit support array to include comments, or "my comments not showing on post" but nothing about getting the comments to display in the editor.
[image: supports array]

if someone could walk me through adding the comment box, id appreciate that.

also If you need to see some code or files let me know, and I can add those. or you can check the Chapters-for-authors plugin found in wordpress plugin library

https://wordpress.com/plugins/chapters-for-authors